# How to export ByteArray from native iOS library to Xamarin binding Library?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding, xamarin.ios

Native iOS library API:
- void getCamImage(Byte[])data withWidth:(size_t)width withHeight:(size_t)height withStride:(size_t)stride ;

In the Binding DLL project, i tried the following:
 [Export("getCamImage:withWidth:withHeight:withStride:")]
 void GetCamImage(Byte[] buffer, int width, int height, int stride);

Tried byte[] instead of Byte[]. Getting the following error:
error CS0452: The type 'byte' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'NSArray.FromNSObjects(params T[])'

Question : how to export the ByteArray parameter as?

Comment: I think byte[] should be the right type in C# for Byte[] in Native iOS. I did not get the error when I use your c# code in my project.

Comment: Hi @JackHua-MSFT I used objective sharpie to convert my FAT library (.a file) to AppDefiniftion.cs and StructsAndEnums.cs . When I try to build the binding library project to get the DLL , it is still giving me the above mentioned project. Are there any project settings required ?

Comment: You can follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=macos) to learn setting requirements.

Comment: The interface in which the API is exported, has [BaseType(typeof(NSobject))]. So in the generated code , it creates a var buff = NSArray.fromNSObjects(bufer) and that is creating the issue.

Comment: byte in C# is struct and you can't pass it as an object. How about [convert byte array to object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33022788/10539446) first.

Comment: The native iOS Api takes Byte[] as parameter. how will i pass it down to the native iOS library as native library ?

Comment: Sorry, I does not get your point. You can open a free xamarin ticket [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6]) for more help if needed.