# How to convert a Byte array to list of object c#?

Tags: c#, .net, byte

I have a byte array and need to convert that to a list of an object.
Say the byte array has this

```
[{name:'ABC',DOB:'01-01-2020'},{name:'XYZ',DOB:'01-03-2020'}]
```

I have a class

```
public class sample{
public string name {get; set;}
public DateTime DOB {get; set;}
}
```

I need to get the data from the byte array as a list of the class sample `List<Sample>`
How can I achieve this?

Comment: I see no byte array here, more like some mangled json. Are you saying that text `[{name:'ABC',DOB:'01-01-2020'},{name:'XYZ',DOB:'01-03-2020'}]` is actually an array of byte in textual representation just for this example? or are you confused what a byte array actually is

Comment: The byte array is from an API call. When the API call is done through browser this is the JSON I get. Added that as an example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert byte array to any type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022660/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-any-type)

Comment: Show how you are calling the webapi... minimally, this is likely an easy fix if you are using HttpClient

Comment: The API call is a URL - http://baseURL/api/controller/parameter1/parameter2
It returns a ByteSyncArray

Comment: Are you using HttpClient to call this?

Comment: Yes. I am using HttpClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code

```
List<Sample> sampleList = JsonConverter.DeserializeObject<List<Sample>>(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the stream, pass the stream to the *Text.Json* `DeserializeAsync` for a minimally allocated lifestyle.

```
using var response = await client
   .GetAsync(new Uri("blahblahblahy"));

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

await using var contentStream = await response
   .Content
   .ReadAsStreamAsync();

var result = await JsonSerializer.
   DeserializeAsync<Sample>(contentStream);
```

<sub>*Note : Technically (in most cases) you don't need to use the using statements here, However there are certain cases you do, so my advice is just do it*</sub>

Comment: Thanks. If I were to get a JSON string as the input, then can I use the same logic to get List<Sample> ?